The $L^\infty$ boundedness of the resolvent of Harmonic Oscillator in terms of seminorms
I am reading Watanabe's book "Lectures on Stochastic Differential Equations and Malliavin Calculus". In Page 48, it is said that by means of (damped) harmonic oscillator $1+|x|^2-\Delta$, we can define $\mathcal{S}_{2k}$ to be the completion of the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, where k is an interger under the norm
$$\|\phi\|_{2k}=\|(1+|x|^2-\Delta)^k\phi\|_\infty,\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d).$$
then we can obtain a nuclear space structure of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, given by
$$\mathcal{S}_{2k+2}\subseteq\mathcal{S}_{2k}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq\mathcal{S}_2\subseteq S_0=C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)\subseteq\mathcal{S}_{-2}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq\mathcal{S}_{-2k}\subseteq\mathcal{S}_{-2k-2}.$$
Since $\mathcal{S}=\mathop{\cap}_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal{S}_{2k}$, it seems that for any seminorms given by
$$\|f\|_{p,k}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\big||x|^p\nabla^kf(x)\big|,$$
there exist some $m$ and $C>0$ that depends on $p,k$ such that
$$\|\phi\|_{p,k}\leq C\|\phi\|_{2m}. \tag{1}$$
I wonder how to proof (1)?
I can prove that $\|\cdot\|_{2k}$ is increasing in $m$ since $\Delta f\leq 0$ at maximum point of $f$.
A similar proof is given in Page 277 of https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/current_version.pdf, but $\mathcal{B}_k$ in this book is not equal to $\mathcal{S}_{2k}$ in our case, since their seminorms are different. I wonder if there is a proof on (1), with dimension is larger than 1 and different seminorm.
